# Monthly reputation change showing +500 however reputation tab shows nothing

Tags: bug, reputation, users-page

According to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/109899/redundant-aunt?tab=reputation), the reputation of a certain math.SE user has increased by 500 points this month (July). But according to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month), the reputation of that same user hasn't changed since June the first. What can explain that?

Comment: Most likely a retracted bounty of 500, this will not leave a trace in the profile, however the monthly gain is taking the data from some source that isn't synched in such edge cases.

Comment: Shows 500 both for month and quarter. (I was guessing bug before Shadow mentioned a possible retracted bounty.)

Comment: @bad_coder the bug, in case my above assumption is correct, is the lack of synchronization of the monthly source, yes.

Comment: It's a nice round number, vote reversals and user removals are accounted for correctly in the users page...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a 500 bounty retraction as others have mentioned in the comments. Retracting this bounty does not leave any traces in the reputation league, but it shows up in the user's profile.

Comment: Well that's just a guess, hence only a comment. Better have staff confirm it first. (So can't upvote, though not downvoting either.)